# Socket open all the time or just open when needed?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm coding an application where the client app needs to authenticate with a server to log in and the every half hour send a packet and receive some info and then sleep for another half hour.

Would the proper way be to start the socket everytime and close after packet sent and received. Or should i keep them open and connected at all time ?.

There's gonna be 100+ clients running simultanious, connecting to the server.

Btw the data sent is very important that it is sent and retrieved in MAX 5-10 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely, it's better to open a new connection each time and close it immediately after. Opening a new connections doesn't take long and 5-10 secs requirement is more than easy to meet with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Idle connection lasting for half an hour is very likely to be killed by some routers/firewalls. Establishing TCP/IP connection introduces some cost, but compared to 5-10 seconds every 30 minutes it is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I leave my TCP sockets open, but it depends on what the server needs to do with those connections.  In this case, I'd probably close them.  Here's the rule of thumb I usually follow:

If you're authenticating every time your client sends data to the server, then it's probably easy for your server to tell "who is who" and you should be able to close it every time.

If your client only authenticates the first time it sends data to the server, and your server needs to maintain a mapping of some key to client connections, then it might be better to leave the connection open.